# update month column from date column in the same table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a data that has a transaction Date [DATETIME] and i'm trying to have a query that go to each transaction row and get the month and year based on the transaction_Date and update the month column for big number of tranasction.

example

```
ID      Trans_Date              Month
01      01/01/2020              012020
02      02/01/2020              012020
03      01/05/2020              052020
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestions for what? You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, the question is how to update the month column to update its value based on the month of the date retrieved from the date field.

Comment: That should be in the question, not the comments, Samer.

Answer (score 1):

Do this using a computed column:

```
alter table t add month as (format(trans_date, 'MMyyyy'));
```

You can do something like this using an `update`.  But that is silly.  The values will not be correct on new rows or on updates to existing rows.  With a computed column, the values are always correct.

You can, of course, express this as an `update`:

```
update t
    set month = format(trans_date, 'MMyyyy');
```

If some of the values are already correct, then add a `where` clause:  `where month <> format(trans_date, 'MMyyyy')`.

Comment: it's a one-time thing to fix that colmun

Comment: @SamerAjlawi . . . I think that illustrates my point that a computed column is better in this case.  With a computed column, values would never get out-of-synch.

Comment: actually i don't control this and it's controlled by other application, the case here is the user need to do some changes from a non- Gregorian month to Gregorian month , this need to be done only once on the cut off date and after that the app will take care of the finance month/period.

Answer (score -1):

Hi just managed to do it this way:

UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[TABLE]
SET [MONTH]= FORMAT(TRANS_DATETIME,'yyyy0MM');